# Visual Studio 2015 - Start Website without connecting to it

Tags: visual-studio-2015, iis-express

For accesing my website, I have to press Run, then, I can access it.

After 30 secs, I am given this error from Visual Studio: `Unable to connect to the configured Web development server` and the website becomes unaccesible.

How to overcome this¿? I want to start the website without trying to connect to it, because it becomes unaccesible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I have found out the best is to run manually the `iisexpress.exe`

Comment: Have you tried with "Start without Debugging" / Ctrl+ F5 from visual studio?